# Gradle: project.buildDir is deprecated

Tags: gradle

In my `build.gradle.kts` file I use the following setting:

```
project.buildDir = file(System.getenv("TMP_GRADLE_BUILD_DIR") + "my_project_name")
```

But in my Gradle API version (`gradle-kotlin-dsl-8.6.jar`) the property `buildDir` is deprecated with no clear recommendations about the appropriate replacement (at least I could not find them in reasonable time).

**Question:** Can you suggest an appropriate way of defining the build directory using environment variables?

**Motivation:** My project directory is subject to backing up, and I don't want to back up the generated artifacts.

**Reference:** In Maven this is achieved with the following setting:

```
     <build>
        <directory>${TMP_MAVEN_BUILD_DIR}${project.artifactId}</directory>
        ...
    </build>
```

Comment: does `setBuildDir` not work for you?

Comment: Yes, setting `buildDir` works. The concern is just about its deprecated state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`project.buildDir` has been replaced by `project.layout.buildDirectory` (see [version 8 upgrade instructions](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_8.html#project_builddir)).

This is of type [`DirectoryProperty`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/DirectoryProperty.html), which has a method `fileValue` for setting the property with `java.io.File` instances. Thus you can write, in Groovy:

```
layout.buildDirectory.fileValue file(System.getenv("TMP_GRADLE_BUILD_DIR") + "my_project_name")
```

and in Kotlin:

```
layout.buildDirectory.fileValue(file(System.getenv("TMP_GRADLE_BUILD_DIR") + "my_project_name"))
```

Comment: Looks like working, thanks! I corrected it a little bit: `layout.buildDirectory.fileValue(file(System.getenv("TMP_GRADLE_BUILD_DIR") +
  "my_project_name"))`.

Comment: Great... I had written it for a Groovy build script.